# MySQL Workbench: no changes in database on delete routins in Routine Group at EER Diagram

Tags: mysql-workbench

There are 2 pages in Workbench: MySQL Model(myDB.mwb) and EER Diagram.
Deleting routins in Routine Group at EER Diagram does not affect routins at MySQL Model(myDB.mwb) page. But if i delete a routine at MySQL Model(myDB.mwb) page it will be deleted at EER Diagram. Other objects like tables at EER Diagram works fine. Is it a bug?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Try making a change to one of te routines and see if ti is reflected.

Comment: This question should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com. And it needs a lot more details, i.e. an exact list of steps that you did, what platform WB runs on etc. Also check the log file (see Help menu) if there's anything useful.